# How to get rid of false jinja syntax errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, flask, jinja2

```
<button type="button" onClick="deleteNotif({{ notif.id }})">delete</button>
```

This code underlines the brackets as "," expected. This is a false error because it works fine when run. Is there a way to remove the false errors and stop it from happening again. It makes it difficult to debug sometimes because it shows these as errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKQfC.png)

Cant find how to remove squiggles

Comment: the same reason all your `{% %}` elements are all white: **Change to a different languageId**, One that knows Jinja syntax